# Nightbot command - !uptime combined with a different command, is it possible?

Tags: command, twitch

I don't know if I'm posting to the right place or what but I was wondering if someone could help me with a Nightbot command I want to make.
I have the !uptime command and I have a !rage command which only retrieves one value. Now I'd like to combine the two into a command that would retrieve 5 or 6 different values (stages of rage in this situation) depending on what value !uptime would retrieve. So basically if I have been streaming for an hour !rage would say minimum but if for 5 hours it would say critical or something.

How is this possible? Someone pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to https://nightbot.tv/commands/custom and simply add these two commands

> command : message : alias

1. !hour : `$(eval var index = $(1); const options=["min","avg","max","babyRage"]; options[index] )`
2. !rage : `$(urlfetch https://beta.decapi.me/twitch/uptime/itsashawe)` : !hour

**NOTE:** Remember to use your channel name instead of mine (itsashawe). Make sure you add `!hour` as alias in the `!rage` command.

P.S.
I've used an api to make it simpler. The rage command calls the hour command which gets the hours, minutes and seconds. The rage command uses `$(1)` i.e. the first argument i.e. the hour and uses it as an index to get values from options which you can change according to your use.

Comment: Thank you very much dude! I’ll make sure to try it asap

Comment: If it works, do mark the answer as correct

Comment: It works just fine, just one thing, is there a way to give the “hour 0” a value as well? Because until I haven’t reached the first hour of my stream it just says something like not defined or so.

Comment: Just add whatever you want to show in the hour 0 in the beginning of the options array and remove -1 in the statement "options[index-1]" so it will simply be options[1], I'll edit the answer

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll try it and hopefully not forget to get back to you if it works! Cheers for all the help!